# I get wrong and signed value in 'C' language

Tags: c, turbo-c++

I am using Turbo C++.

This is code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
 clrscr();
 
 printf("%d",1000*100);
 printf("\n%d",1000*10);

 getch();
}
```

Output:

```
-31072
10000
```

1. Why does the first `printf()` give wrong and signed value? Whether integer have range (-2147483648 to +2147483647).
2. And in second `printf()` it gives right value with right sign. How?

Comment: Find the range of your `int`s with `#include <limits.h>` and `printf("ints range from %d to %d on this implementation.\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);`

Comment: It is always better to write for instance `int number = 1000*100; printf (... number ...);` Then you certainly know which object type is passed to `printf`. Also you get a compiler error when the constant that you want to assign to `number` is too large.

Comment: 'Kolodez' sir I tried this thing also but the output is same.

Comment: And if you set `int number = 100000;`, you do not get a compiler warning?

Comment: What is the output of the program that pmg suggested in his comment?

Comment: This is old C compiler and it seems `int` is 16 bit.

Comment: 'Kolodez' sir same output after assing

Comment: "I am using Turbo C++". That's the problem.

Comment: 1) Turbo C++ was released in 1990, which is is far older than the first C++ standard (C++98), therefore it doesn't compile C++ compliant code. Turbo C is also older than the first C standard. 2) C and C++ are very different languages, so Turbo C++ doesn't compile C code. 3) Turbo C and Turbo C++ are 16-bit DOS programs and int has only 16 bits

Comment: Launched my VM with TurboC :-) https://i2.paste.pics/fc6f4d1ce9bec7bb2e0f6533ffa52e94.png and https://i2.paste.pics/1ebb3f3d1c5da1a51df4c4d3c926bf84.png

Answer (score 1):

1000*100=100'000. If your `int` is 16-bits-long, then the result is *higher* than the maximum supported value, which is 32'767. If you're running a 32-bit OS or you're making a 32-bit program, consider using "long", which is 4 bytes in the case of 32-bits OSs or 8 bytes for 64-bit ones; the highest supported value will respectively be: 2'147'483'647, 9'223'372'036'854'775'807.
To have a `long` as an output, use one of the following format specifiers: `%l`, `%ld` or `%li`.
To see the maximum value for `int`, include `limits.h` and check (see the last source).

Hope it helps.

Sources:

- [C - Data Types](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm#:%7E:text=the%20upcoming%20chapters.-,Integer%20Types,-The%20following%20table)
- [Long format specifier(s)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/format-specifiers-in-c#:%7E:text=ld%20or%20%25li-,Long,-%25lf)
- [INT_MAX](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/int_max-int_min-cc-applications/#:%7E:text=if%20(num1%20%3E-,INT_MAX,-%2D%20num2))

Comment: "consider using "long", which is 4 bytes in the case of 32-bits OSs or 8 bytes for 64-bit ones;" -- This statement is not correct for all platforms. For example, on 64-bit Windows, using the Microsoft compiler, a `long` is `4` bytes.

Comment: ''Luca' sir I change format specifier to %ld but the output is '34464' and it is still wrong

Comment: Sir, When I changed one value into float and also changed format specifier into %f then it gives right answer with right sign. But why it is not giving right answer when I assigned as int type. And about Turboc++ compiler it have (-2147483648 To +21474483647) range of signed int. Then why it gives wrong answer?

Comment: `1000 * 100` is done entirely in `int`; you need `1000L * 100` to the multiplication in `long` ... or `long a = 1000; long b = 100; long c = a * b; printf("%ld * %ld = %ld\n", a, b, c);`

Answer (score -2):

You are having an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Turbo C/C++ is a 16-bit compiler. It is not used for development. Stop using it as soon as you can.

The `int` type can store values between `-32768` and `32767`. The following program demonstrates.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int i;
    clrscr();
    for(i = 0; i >= 0; i++);
    printf("%d\n", i); // upper limit of int
    printf("%d\n", i - 1); //lower limit of int
    getch();
}
```

To get the answer you want, you need to cast that number to `long`.

```c
printf("%d",1000*100);
```

should be

```c
printf("%ld", (long)1000*100);
```

See it in action at [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/JZ-mBOxsF).

Comment: When `i` reaches the limit you invoke Undefined Behaviour with `i++`.

Comment: @pmg TurboC itself is non-standard.

Comment: Agree .. it's mostly C89 compliant though